# Use Case: User uses input device

Tags: architecture, uml, software-design, use-case-diagram

I am creating a use case diagram for a scenario where a user uses various input devices (tablet, wireless pen, etc) to interact with a system. For that part, because users *only* interact with the system through devices, I currently have the diagram like this...

[image: diagram]

I know that devices and systems and such can be use case actors, but I have not seen this kind of diagram design before where one actor uses another to use services. Is this viable as a use case diagram?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to model `do this by device1`, `do that by device1`, `do this by device2` etc. as separate use cases. For showing that they actually share some core behaviour, you can define abstract (parent) use cases for `do this` and `do that` and use [generalization](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/use-case.html#generalization) relationships.

[This article](https://www.modernanalyst.com/Careers/InterviewQuestions/tabid/128/ID/365/What-is-use-case-generalization.aspx) and this [article have](https://sceweb.uhcl.edu/helm/RationalUnifiedProcess/process/modguide/md_ucgen.htm) have good explanations on the concept of generalization.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take that. And I still have work to do!